# Multiple time series prediction with LSTM Autoencoder in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I'm trying to build an LSTM autoencoder as shown [here](http://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).
My code:

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(window_length, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(window_length)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

model = Model(inputs, decoded)
model.fit(batch_size=512)
```

The shape of the dataset is: (rows, window_length, input_dim).
When I try to call fit() I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (512, 221) for Tensor u'lstm_2_target:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?)'
```

This model it's really simple, I don't understand what is the problem.

**EDIT**
Model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 10, 221)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               179200    
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVecto (None, 10, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 10, 221)           309400    
=================================================================
Total params: 488,600
Trainable params: 488,600
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Are you loading weights from somewhere? What is the model summary and the shapes of X and Y? Please provide a minimum info to answer this question.

Comment: Did you make sure that `window_length` and `timesteps` are equal?

Comment: @DanielMöller Sorry about timesteps, I meant window_length. Updated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: @MrfksIV I never figured out how to handle this issue. But keep an eye on this question for further news.

Answer (score 0):

If the code was run exactly as above, it probably needs to be compiled:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['acc', 'cosine_proximity'])
```